# Install Package in PySpark running on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I need to install a package in AWS EMR PySpark kernel. I use the following code

```
sc.install_pypi_package("statsmodels")
```

On doing this I get the error

```
statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c:39:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How do I resolve this issue. There are more packages like s3fs which give the same error when I try to install them.

After a google search I did the following

```
sudo yum install python-dev
```

but this returns

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
3 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package python-dev available.
Error: Not tolerating missing names on install, stopping.
```

I have very less idea of how EMR runs and this is not something I understand.

Comment: where are you running this command? `sudo yum install python-dev`

Answer (score 1):

We use custom Python libraries invoked via Pandas UDFs on EMR clusters. We use the following set up to package up all our dependencies into a Docker image that is in turn used by EMR:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-docker.html

I will be honest that it wasn't the easiest to set it up, but now that we have it, it's great. For one thing, we can ensure that the version of all dependencies (we use NumPy, Pandas, Statsmodels) is the same in prod as what we use in dev, so there is no surprises where something works in dev but not in prod.